# JQuery in ASP.Net Web form with a master page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have a page named CoursesPage.aspx and it has a Master Page. In CoursesPage.aspx I'm using the autocomplete jquery on the course name for better searching. This is my script code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function LoadList() {
            var ds = null;
            ds = <%=listFilter %>
        $("#txtName3").autocomplete({
            source: ds
        });
        }
    </script>
```

This code works fine if I don't use the Master Page. However, I can't put this in the Content tag in the CoursesPage.aspx. It needs to be in the head tag but I can't add that in a content tag.
Please guide me.

Secondly, this function is called on the load of the body tag but I can't add a body tag either.

Comment: Do you mean it needs to be in the "head" tag?

Comment: yeah. I wrote head but it didnt show up.

Answer (score 2):

In your master page there are two ContentPlaceHolder tags, one in the head and the other in the body.
You'll have to add two Content tags in your Courses.aspx page and set the one of the ContenetPlaceHolderID attributes to the master page head's ContentPlaceHolder.
For example:
Your master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="ResponsiveTemplate.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body>
</html>
```

and your aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="ResponsiveTemplate.WebForm2" %>

<asp:Content ID="content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function LoadList() {
        var ds = null;
        ds = <%=listFilter %>
    $("#txtName3").autocomplete({
        source: ds
    });
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="content2" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Did this. But the jquery isn't still working. Because the body tag needs to be like this: body onload=LoadList()

Comment: You can simply add $(document).ready and place your LoadList script inside it or just call that function in the document.ready event

Answer (score 1):

You can add a content place holder in the head of the masterpage for example:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Then in the page, you can add your script to the head of the master page, by wrapping it in a content tag that references `head` like so:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function LoadList() {
            var ds = null;
            ds = <%=listFilter %>
        $("#txtName3").autocomplete({
            source: ds
        });
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

This cannot be nested in any other content tags.

Comment: Did this. But the jquery isn't still working. Because the body tag needs to be like this: body onload=LoadList()

Comment: Just add `$(LoadList);` at the end of your script.  It will fire `LoadList()` when the document has loaded.

Comment: That's odd.  Try `$(function(){LoadList();});`

Comment: I tried using window.onload = function and using $(document).ready but it didn't work. Then I just tried a simple pop up and that didn't work either. The javascript isnt loading. I guess thats where the problem is

Comment: Check the path of your javascript files.  `js/jquery-1.8.3.js` may work with the child page, but it may not work with the master page.  You may have to do `../js/jquery-1.8.3.js` or `~/js/jquery-1.8.3.js`.

Comment: Can you post your master and child pages?

Comment: Master Page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>SZABIST HelpDesk</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

Comment: Content of child
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
   
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function LoadList() {
            var ds = null;
            ds = <%=listFilter %>
        $("#txtName3").autocomplete({
            source: ds
        });
        }
    </script>


</asp:Content>

Comment: Okay, well first off, you're loading jquery twice.  You only need it in the master or the child, not both.  But that shouldn't cause your issue.  For the script where you have your function.  Remove `language="javascript"` and add `type="text/javascript"`.  Third, I don't see anywhere where you actually call LoadList().  Although, you don't have to put that (or the function declaration) in the head.  Just the links to jquery need to go there.  So you can add the script in the regular content of your child page.

Comment: In that script you need to declare the function (which you have) and call the function, I recommend the second one I posted `$(function(){LoadList();});`  If that doesn't work, and you get an error message.  Then jquery isn't loading.  Which means that the files you're linking to aren't there or are corrupt.

Comment: Where exactly do I put $(function(){LoadList();}); ?

Comment: In the body of your child page.  So, you should have two content sections in your child page.  You can add new script tags at the bottom of the second context.

Comment: It didn't work. I added an alert in that same function just to check, that pops up. So its not the fault of the files.

Comment: Wait, so the function IS firing?

Comment: Go into the console, and see what error messages are firing.

Comment: yes the function is firing. But there are no errors in the console. and no warnings either

Comment: Okay, so if it's firing then the head issue is solved.  But there is a datasource issue with the jquery ui control.  I would recommend posting a new question to solve that issue.