# Using jQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-interface, jquery-ui, webforms

Okay, this might sound like a stupid question, but where exactly do I add the line `<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in a .aspx page? I am newbie to both ASP.NET and jQuery. I am given a half complete ASP.NET project and I need to use jQuery to configure the UI. Everywhere I searched, it says first insert the above line inside the `<head>` tag. But my Default.aspx page does not have a `<head>` tag. Instead it has `<asp:Content>` and `<asp:UpdatePanel>` tags.

Comment: if you have a master page then include it there. place a head tag in the master page and place jquery inside head.

Comment: Before uploading any question, try to google it. If you would search it, you would find millions of result there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find you master page, normally it is called Site.master, and it's located in the root of the solution

For example

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">

        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Masterpage in webform is the place where you include all common css, javascripts. this can be found in another question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664066/jquery-in-asp-net-web-form-with-a-master-page?answertab=active#tab-top)